# converting XML using LINQ and Storing to a datagridview table using C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview

I have this XML File.

```
<Address>
    <Data2>
        <Person>
          <EMPL_NUM>>100</EMPL_NUM>
          <NAME>Carl</NAME>
          <ID_NUM>1</ID_NUM>
          <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <EMPL_NUM>200</EMPL_NUM>
          <NAME>Mark</NAME>
          <ID_NUM>2</ID_NUM>
          <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
        </Person>
        <Person>
          <EMPL_NUM>300</EMPL_NUM>
          <NAME>Tanner</NAME>
          <ID_NUM>3</ID_NUM>
          <IsRequired>0</IsRequired>
        </Person>
 </Data2>
</Address>
```

I am trying to store to a `datagridview` all the data of `Person` that has `ID_NUM = 1`.

Output to datagrid should be:

```
EMPL_NUM  |  Name  |  ID_NUM  |  IsRequired                  
  100     |  Carl  |    1     |      0
```

Below is my current code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(path);     
var mySteps = (from s in doc.Descendants("Address")                           
               select new
               {
                   Id = int.Parse(s.Element("EMPL_NUM").Value),
                   Name = s.Element("NAME").Value,
                   MD_ID = s.Elements("ID_NUM").Where(x => x.Element("MD_ID").Value == IdNum),
                   Description = s.Element("IsRequired").Value
               }).ToList();
datagridview.datasource = mysteps.ToList();
```

I keep on getting the error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

Instead of

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(path);
```